# A monitor connected by HDMI not recognized by Intel HD Graphics

Tags: debian, graphics, hdmi

I've just installed a fresh Debian 9.4.0 on a PC with a PRIME Z370-A motherboard (Integrated Graphics Processor- Intel® HD Graphics) and an additional ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1070 graphics card. I'd like to use the GTX 1070 for computations. The monitor ProLite XUB2792QSU-B1 is connected to the Intel card via a HDMI cable.

Now, after I logged in to my user, the resolution was 1024x768 (instead of 2560x1440). These are the results of `xrandr` command:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

These are the currently available controllers:

```
lspci -k
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
        Kernel modules: i915
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
        Kernel modules: nouveau
```

The `xrandr --listproviders` command yields `Providers: number : 0`

What should I do to be able to use my monitor at its full available resolution?

Answer (score 1):

## General information

Unless on both ends there is HDMI version 2.0, you would have to use DisplayPort.

## Specifically to your case

Your monitor has one HDMI version 1.4, which has limitations, you may want to see [specification on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4). You will have to use DisplayPort.

Comment: I tried to connect the monitor using a DisplayPort cable, but the result is the same - the only available resolution is 1024x768.

Comment: @PawełKłeczek DisplayPort <-> DisplayPort directly? Don't use any reductions.